# Query string to select configurable variation

Tags: configurable-product, querystring

I want to select the configurable variation on page load based on the query string parameter. I cannot find anything on google for this so I am guessing it is not core magento functionality.

Does anybody know of a simple way to do this?

Example URL: `test.com/test-product?p=3245643243254`